# Issue with looping through a column in excel looking for cells with a particular value

Tags: vba, excel

What i am trying to do is look into another excel sheet and pick out information from the rows that have the same string as another in a different sheet. I need to loop though the list and pick out only a few values from the rows. I am still a long shot from achieving this so first im just looking into the sheet1 trying to compare it to the other cell in sheet2.If they have the same value i want to pick out certain cell value in the row where they find the same value and then put them into the other sheet. Apologies if this does not make sense. Here is my code so far. Also i get an error 'object defined when i run the code. When i debug its the line with the if statement thats going wrong

```
Sub Awesome_macro()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Counter As Integer
      ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
      NumRows = Range("H15", Range("H15").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      ' Select cell a1.
      Range("H16").Select
      ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
      For x = 1 To NumRows
         If StrComp(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(H, 15).Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(A, 1).Value) = 0 Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D15").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")
         End If
         ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sure you don't get an "object defined" error? Unless `H` and `A` are variables holding numbers or letters you need to use `"H"` and `"A"`. Also, the order of parameters of `.Cells` is `(row,column)`. Finally, you need to make the contents of your loop dependent on `x` or it will execute for row 15 over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Try following piece of code:

```
Value2Find = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(A, 1).Value
Row_Num = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Value2Find, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found a way to to it but its not looping through correctly

Sub Awesome_macro()

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
  ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  NumRows = Range("H15", Range("H15").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  ' Select cell a1.
  Range("H16").Select
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For x = 1 To NumRows
     If (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H15").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value) Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D15").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3")
     End If
     ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next
```

End Sub

Its printing something into the sheet2 now so the comparing the values and printing on the page works. just need to figure out how to loop it properly